# delete all empty directories starting with

Tags: linux

How to delete all empty directories starting with `201` ?

The command must *not* execute recursive.. Only directories in the current directory

```
find /var/www -type d -name "201*" -exec rm {} \
```

This returns

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Comment: You missed the last `;`, `find /var/www -type d -name "201*" -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: have added some info.. the command must not execute recursively..

Comment: use the `-maxdepth 1` option for avoiding descending into dirs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply run

```
rmdir 201*/
```

`rmdir` will only delete empty directories and `201*/` matches all subdirectories of the current one starting with `201`.

if you don't want to change to the respective directory before, you can use the full path:

```
rmdir /var/www/201*/
```

Comment: how do I add the current dir to the command?

Comment: I am not a hundred percent sure what you mean. Do you mean the full path to the directory where the 201 directories reside? That would be `rmdir /var/www/201*/`

Comment: I found out `rmdir 201*/ /var/www/current_dir`

Comment: your solution works too.. both works :)